# How to be notified when i receive an alphanumeric sms on iphone

Tags: iphone, sms

How can I  be notified when i receive a SMS with an alphanumeric number on the iPhone.

For example, I want to get a notification when I receive a SMS from my bank which sends SMS messages from phone numbers like: ABCBANK

[image]